# No se captura y trata correctamente la excepcion la primera vez que ocurre

Tags: excepciones, symfony4

Tengo el siguiente problema: cuando el usuario intenta ejecutar alguna acción en una aplicación Symfony4  cada vez que existe error de conexión con la base de datos (digamos por una parada del SGBD) internamente se redirecciona al action `renderLoginFormAction` debido a que no es posible comprobar las credenciales del usuario contra la BD; ahora bien la primera vez en el action me salta el mensaje feo de problema de conexión al SGBD pero las próximas veces que el usuario continua "clickeando" en alguna acción el `renderLoginFormAction` sí captura correctamente el problema de conexion al SGBD y lanza correctamente el error al usuario, definido en el bloque `catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException $doctrineExc)`

Este es el código de action:

```
public function renderLoginFormAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        try {
            $aplicacion = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Aplicacion::class)->find(1);
            if (is_null($aplicacion) || ($aplicacion->getInstalada() === false || $aplicacion->getConfigurada() === false)) {
                return $this->render('Install/index.html.twig');
            }

            $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
            $ultimoUsuario = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

            return $this->render('Usuario/login.html.twig', array(
                        'last_username' => $ultimoUsuario,
                        'error' => $error,
            ));
        } catch (TableNotFoundException $tbNotFoundExc) {
            $logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, $tbNotFoundExc->getMessage()));

            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                return new Response("Verifique el esquema de la base de datos haya sido subido al servidor.", 500);
            }
            throw new \Exception("Verifique el esquema de la base de datos haya sido subido al servidor.", 500);
        } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException $doctrineExc) {
            $logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, $doctrineExc->getMessage()));

            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                return new Response("No fue posible conectar con la base de datos.", 500);
            }
            throw new \Exception("No fue posible conectar con la base de datos.", 500);
        } catch (\Exception $exc) {
            $logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, $exc->getMessage()));

            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                return new Response("Ocurrió un error inesperado. Contacte con el administrador del sistema.", 500);
            }
            throw new \Exception($exc->getMessage(), 500);
        }
    }
```

Esta es la primera vez que el usuario intenta realizar una operación y existe problema de conexión con el SGBD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error tratado por el bloque catch `ConnectionException` las próximas veces que el usuario intenta ejecutar una operación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la excepción en el entorno dev la primera vez que ocurre:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has conseguido saber cuál era el problema? Me interesa . ¿Puede ser que tenga que ver con el orden en la carga? Yo, para capturar las excepciones y manejarlas a mi gusto uso [los Event Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/event_dispatcher.html), por si te puede ayudar

Comment: @msalinas no aún no, he cambiado el orden de los bloques catch y nada. Voy a probar mediante eventos como me comentas

Comment: pues a ver si va bien con esta nueva forma y consigues que te funcione 